# Ubuntu 18.04: run a shell script from the indicator tray

Tags: 18.04, indicator, system-tray

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a program I can install which will allow me to run a script from the indicator tray? I'm not sure if that's the correct name, so here's a picture:

[image: indicator tray]

Thank you for your assistance!